# Print compiled sqlalchemy query

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

Is there a way I can print a query created by sqlalchemy

```
emp = session.query(Employee).filter(*empfilters).order_by(Employee.Name).all()
```

I've tried doing `str(emp)`, `emp.statement.compile(dialect=postgresql.dialect(), compile_kwargs={"literal_binds": True})` or other solutions from SO, but couldn't reproduce anything.
The `*empfilters` again here comes from other tables (part of one-many join) so I wanted to check what exactly it's being compiled to.

The error if I try to do it by above is - `'list' object has no attribute 'statement'`

Comment: The query ends at `order_by(Employee.Name)`. When you use `.all()` at the end, the query runs and returns a list, hence your error message.

If you remove `.all()` you should be able to examine the query string.

Comment: `global name 'postgresql' is not defined` -- Do I need to add it @ac24?

Comment: Just `str(emp)` should let you view the query in native sql. If you are having other issues please include more code to demonstrate `empfilters` etc.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to print it by removing `all()` and then doing `print emp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the recommendation from @ac24, removed the `.all()` from the query and then `print emp` did the trick.